# can you install iis 7.5 full version on windows 7?

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-7.5, wcf

I have windows 7 professional installed on my pc. I have IIS 7.5 installed, but not sure if that is express edition or not.

I deployed my WCF app on the IIS server. kept getting this error message.

```
The protocol 'net.msmq' is not supported.
```

did a little bit research found out that IIS express edition will not support msmq protocol.

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/introduction-to-iis-express/iis-express-faq

in the "program files" folder, I see IIS folder and IIS express folder, they both there.  but In IIS folder, I only have 2 subfolders (Microsoft Web Deploy, Microsoft Web Deploy V3). in IIS Express folder, there are alot more files.  I do believe I have express edition installed.

How can I confirm that my IIS is express edition.

where to download the full edition to install on windows 7 ?

Comment: Check out this stack overflow article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399280/wcf-msmq-binding-with-an-iis-service-how-to-instantiate-the-service

Comment: Windows 7 in not a server operating system so we don't support it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS 7.5 is part of Windows 7, you enable it by adding Windows features. IIS Express has to be downloaded and installed.

Both version can run at the same time and can even serve the same web-site at the same time (on different ports).

IIS proper runs as a Windows service, there are various ways to check for a running service, one is using PowerShell:

```
get-service | where {$_.Name -eq "w3svc"}
```

IIS Express is a user process which has to be started manually (or by Visual Studio or Web Matrix). It usually uses ports other than 80 to serve your web site.

If you are using "Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager" to manage your site, then you are using the full IIS.